Tesseract not reading text good when deploy
I'd be happy to help with Tesseract wisdom. I mainly use it to extract text from WhatsApp conversations. Locally, it works perfectly, extracting all the text without any issues. However, the problem arises when I upload it to the cloud with DJANGO. I've configured everything necessary for Tesseract to work. Locally, I manually installed it because I'm using Windows, and for the server, I simply used Docker. Somehow, I encounter version differences between local and production.
But the main issue is that in the cloud, it misses a lot of text whereas locally, everything comes out perfectly. I tried changing the image to send it from React via API to the cloud and download it to my server, but it remains the same. I really don't know why it sometimes misses text and sometimes works perfectly, even in the cloud, this varies from image to image. Needless to say, I also use CV2 to improve its performance significantly. Would appreciate any help on this matter.
Prompt: What steps have you taken to troubleshoot the Tesseract issue both locally and on the cloud? What are the specific differences you've observed between the successful and unsuccessful cases?
this is my code:
FROM python:3.11.0
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        tesseract-ocr \
        libtesseract-dev \
    && apt-get clean

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --only-upgrade -y libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean

COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /code/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./myapp /code/myapp
COPY ./dateapp /code/dateapp
COPY ./manage.py /code/
...

and this is the part of call to the tesseract (
# Set the path to the directory containing the language data files
lang_data_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
# Ensure that the 'heb.traineddata' file is located in the same directory
heb_traineddata_file = os.path.join(lang_data_dir, 'heb.traineddata')

# Set the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable to the directory containing the language data files
os.environ['TESSDATA_PREFIX'] = lang_data_dir

# # Set the path to the tesseract executable
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/bin/tesseract'

)
please help me to understand why its get worse like that in the deployment. I tried to change the sizes of the image and sometimes it's getting better sometimes not
